# Send Images using RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-c

I want to transfer an image from a client to the server using RabbitMQ. However, from whatever I read, I understood that RabbitMQ can only transfer a stream of text. So how to transfer an image?

Comment: Where did you read that you can only transfer a stream of text? That is false. You can transfer a stream of bytes; which is what an image is.

Comment: https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c/blob/master/examples/amqp_producer.c sends 256-byte messages consisting of byte values `0x00` to `0xFF`

Answer (score 1):

The amqp body is a buffer, you can send what you want.

In general, if you want to send a file, you have to read it and send the buffers.

You should send the file using more publish and not just one, then recreate the file on the consumer side.

You should avoid sending big buffer.

Comment: By default the RabbitMQ broker does not impose any limit on message payload sizes (though its possible to create one). That said, the sender, broker and receiver all must be able to hold the entire message in-memory.

Comment: @alanxz yes, I just suggested having a fixed buffer. Images can be very large, and I saw more than one time problems related to big buffers in term of memory and sockets. Speaking about files it is always a good practice implement a sort of streaming. (In my opinion)  especially if the clients are not in LAN.